# Not able to see the comments on our dashboard

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, accelerated-mobile-page

We have implemented Facebook comments in our AMP pages but not able to see the comments on our [dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/). Has anybod experienced such an issue? Is it something wrong with our AMP implementation or do Facebook comments have this issue on AMP pages?

This is the [script](https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-facebook-comments-0.1.js) that we are using.

Comment: Start by checking what the Open Graph debug tool has to say about the URLs you are pointing the comments plugin to.

Comment: No errors, if that is what you meant. I have edited the question with the script that we are using.

Comment: Got an example URL?

Comment: @CBroe https://justdoc.com/question/caugh-cold-since-one-week-how-to-get-rid-of-caugh

Comment: The debug tool does show errors for that, why did you say it didn’t? The meta tags are present when I view the source code in my browser, but the FB scraper sees something different: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fjustdoc.com%2Fquestion%2Fcaugh-cold-since-one-week-how-to-get-rid-of-caugh - so you need to go do some debugging as to why that happens.

Comment: @CBroe yeah, I have also seen this discrepancy but not able to find what is causing it. The same happens with Twitter cards. Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.